# WCF communication problem

Tags: c#, wcf

In my WCF application I receive an image in base64String format along with some other images..
In order to test my application I have created a small .aspx page which will
send firstname, last name and base64string(image:size 10Kb) to the WCF Sevice.
I am getting the error
"The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: 
Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'SaveData'. 
The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data.
 This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the 
 XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 1, position 15301."

If I send the strings without the base64string(image) i was able to debug the wcf Service code.
But if I add the base64String I am getting this error. 
I have increased all binding values("maxReceivedMessageSize") and other values to maximum.
 Still I am getting this error. Here is my web.config for client and Service.
 Thanks and I really appreciate your help.

Client Web.config

```
 <system.serviceModel>  
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IRESTService1" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
          useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:10255/RESTService1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
        bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IRESTService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IRESTService1"
        name="BasicHttpBinding_IRESTService1" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Service web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>       
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicBinding1" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>      

    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service name="RESTService1">
        <endpoint address=""
          binding="basicHttpBinding" name="MainHttpPoint" contract="RESTService1"  bindingConfiguration="BasicBinding1" />       
      </service>
    </services>

    <!--<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>-->
  </system.serviceModel>
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these lines inside `Binding` tag in web.config file

```
<binaryMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="2147483647" maxWritePoolSize="2147483647">
<readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"   maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
</binaryMessageEncoding>
<httpTransport  decompressionEnabled="True" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"/>
```

[MSDN : binaryMessageEncoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731780.aspx)

hope this help

Comment: Hi Amani, Thanks for your reply. But its not allowing me to add <BinaryMessageEncoding> tag inside <bindings> tag. Any idea where should I add it.

Comment: My friend I said Binding tag, not Bindings.